# GLSL 4.0 mesh rotation messes up normal? help please

Tags: rotation, glsl

Could someone please help me with my OpenGL GLSL 4.0 shader.  The problem i am having is when a 3d (0bj file) is loaded and rendered, all works(lighting good, mesh vertices display great) well except the  normals of the mesh file.  Specifically, when the obj file is rotated in its local/model space the normal does not appear to light mesh in accordance with the light position and its current orientation (I hope that makes some sense).

I believe the problem is with my normal matrix.

Problem: when my 3d mesh rotates, the lighting is meshed up(does not reflect the light position).

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank in advance

VertexShader

```
 #version 400
        //Handle translation, projection, etc
        struct Matrix {
            mat4 mvp;
            mat4 mv;
            mat4 view;
            mat4 projection;
        };  
        struct Light {
            vec3 position;
            vec3 color;
            vec3 direction;
            float intensity;
            vec3 ambient;
        };
        //---------------------------------------------------
        //INPUT
        //---------------------------------------------------
        //Per-Vertex Data
        //---------------------------------------------------
        layout (location = 0) in vec3 inputPosition;
        layout (location = 1) in vec3 inputNormal;
        layout (location = 2) in vec3 inputTexture;
        //--------------------------------------------
        // UNIFORM:INPUT Supplied Data from C++ application
        //--------------------------------------------
        uniform Matrix matrix;
        uniform Light light;
        uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

        out vec3 fragmentNormal;
        out vec3 cameraVector;
        out vec3 lightVector;
        out vec2 texCoord;
        void main() {   
            // output the transformed vertex
            gl_Position = matrix.mvp * vec4(inputPosition,1.0);


            //When using, (vec3,0.0)
            mat3 Normal_Matrix = mat3(    transpose(inverse(matrix.mv))  );


            // set the normal for the fragment shader and
            // the vector from the vertex to the camera
            vec3 vertex     = (matrix.mv * vec4(inputPosition,1.0)).xyz;

            //----------------------------------------------------------
            //The problem (i think) is here
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            fragmentNormal  = normalize(Normal_Matrix * inputNormal);
            cameraVector    = (matrix.mv *vec4(cameraPosition,1.0)).xyz - vertex ;


            lightVector = vertex - (matrix.mv * vec4(light.position,1.0)).xyz;  


            //store the texture data
            texCoord = inputTexture.xy;




        }
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 400


const int   NUM_LIGHTS       = 3;
const float     MAX_DIST         = 15.0;
const float     MAX_DIST_SQUARED = MAX_DIST * MAX_DIST;

const vec3 AMBIENT = vec3(0.152, 0.152, 0.152); //0.2 for all component is a good dark value



struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
    vec3 direction;
    float intensity;
    vec3 ambient;
};

//the image
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

uniform Light light;

//in: used interpolation, must define both in vertex&fragment shader; 


out vec4 finalOutput;


in vec2 texCoord;   //Texture Coordinate
//in: used interpolation, must define both in vertex&fragment shader; 
in vec3 fragmentNormal;
in vec3 cameraVector;
in vec3 lightVector;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texCoord);
    // initialize diffuse/specular lighting
    vec3 diffuse =  vec3(0.005f, 0.005f, 0.005f);
    vec3 specular = vec3(0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f);

    // normalize the fragment normal and camera direction
    vec3 normal     = normalize(fragmentNormal);
    vec3 cameraDir  = normalize(cameraVector);

    // loop through each light

        // calculate distance between 0.0 and 1.0
        float dist = min(dot(lightVector, lightVector), MAX_DIST_SQUARED) / MAX_DIST_SQUARED;
        float distFactor = 1.0 - dist;

        // diffuse
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightVector);
        float diffuseDot = dot(normal, lightDir);

        diffuse += light.color * clamp(diffuseDot, 0.0, 1.0) * distFactor;

        // specular
        vec3 halfAngle = normalize(cameraDir + lightDir);
        vec3 specularColor = min(light.color + 0.8, 1.0);
        float specularDot = dot(normal, halfAngle);
        specular += specularColor * pow(clamp(specularDot, 0.0, 1.0), 16.0) * distFactor;


    vec4 sample0 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    vec3 ambDifCombo = (diffuse + AMBIENT);
    //calculate the final color
    vec3 color = clamp(sample0.rgb * ambDifCombo + specular, 0.0, 1.0);

    finalOutput = vec4(color * vec3(texColor), sample0.a);
}
```

Comment: Does the lighting look completely wrong, or is it just the diffuse or specular?

Comment: the lighting is perfect; the problem is when the mesh rotate where the shading of the mesh does not reflect the the position of the light source.  So one side of the mesh is lit up while the opposite side is not, however the same side that is lit up stays lit up during the entire rotation of the cube.  It should be that when the mesh rotates different parts of the mesh will light up based on which face is facing the light direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not transform your light position. Your light should remain stationary while your mesh rotates. Instead of this:

```
lightVector = vertex - (matrix.mv * vec4(light.position,1.0)).xyz;
```

Do this:

```
lightVector = vertex - light.position;
```

I would also try not transforming your camera position too.

Comment: brilliant suggestion.  I change my vertex shader to lightVector= vertex - (matrix.view * vec4(light.position,1.0)).xyz an all is well now